# Flip X and Y axis on Excel custom chart

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-charts

I've made a chart with Excel 2010's "Combo" option for chart type so I can plot two data series for the same depth points.  The image below shows the default, which is very close to what I want - except I would like to have the axes flipped so that the current X axis, which is depth, is displayed as the Y axis and both primary and secondary current Y axes plot as X axes.  In other words, I'd like to rotate the chart area by 90 degrees clockwise.  The "Switch Row/Column" doesn't do what I want (or expect) and I'm running out of both ideas and patience.  Is there an easy fix?  Or a hard fix?

Here's the plot as-is:
[image]

And here's a dummy plot of the end goal made by rotating the image around in Paint, in case the picture makes it clearer:

[image]

Finally, as was pointed out in the comments, the whole thing looks goofy and might be better plotted as a bar graph with two bars.  I tried this as well and came away almost all set - but the gray bars plot from left to right and the blue bars plot from right to left.  Seems like it should be as simple as changing the "Plot Series On" option to Primary Axis for both, but this destroys the graph.

[image]

Comment: Originally, I had planned for two bars rather than bar and line.  I find that I can do the secondary axis but run into issues when reversing the secondary y axis.  I'll add that to the question above in case it's an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and I think this link has instructions for what you're looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/188064/excel-chart-with-two-x-axes-horizontal-possible